# My dropdown menu in my nav bar isn't aligning

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble aligning my drop down menu in my nav bar, I've tried every suggestion out there. I've tried `left`, `float: left`, `right`, and pretty much everything else. I think it is possibly something interfering. The drop down menu has everything aligned from center to right of the parent menu item.

https://jsfiddle.net/ethacker/j7tgq95j/3/

My html code:

```
<header>
<nav>
    <h1> Welcome to Mommy Madness</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="parentMenu"><a href="../Home/mmHome.html">Home</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="../Home/mmAbout.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Home/mmContact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parentMenu"><a href="../PregnancyPages/preg.html">Pregnancy</a>
            <!--
            Gender Predictions:
            Old Wive's Tale
            Boy vs Girl- The Ramzi Method
            -->
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="../PregnancyPages/pregAdvice.html">Advice</a></li>
                <li><a href="../PregnancyPages/pregGenderPredictions.html">Gender Predictions</a></li>
                <li><a href="../PregnancyPages/pregTTC.html">Trying To Conceive</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parentMenu"><a href="../AllAboutBaby/AllAboutBaby.html">All About Baby</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="../AllAboutBaby/aabFetalDev.html">Fetal Development</a></li>
                <li><a href="../AllAboutBaby/aabGuidelines.html">Guidelines </a> </li>
                <li><a href="../AllAboutBaby/aabMilestones.html"> Milestones</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parentMenu"><a href="../PartyMomma/PartyMomma.html">Party Momma</a>
            <!--
            Birthdays - Link to 1-10th bdays.
            -->
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="../PartyMomma/pmPregAnn.html">Pregnancy Announcement</a></li>
                <li><a href="../PartyMomma/pmGenderReveal.html">Gender Reveal</a></li>
                <li><a href="../PartyMomma/pmBabyShower.html">Baby Shower</a></li>
                <li><a href="../PartyMomma/pmBirthAnn.html">Birth Announcement</a></li>
                <li><a href="../PartyMomma/pmBirthdays.html"> Birthdays</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parentMenu"><a href="../Stations/Stations.html">Stations</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="../Stations/sHospitalBag.html">Hospital Bag</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Stations/sDiaperBag.html">Diaper Bag</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Stations/sChangingStation.html">Changing Station</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Stations/sBabyGear.html">Baby Gear</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parentMenu"><a href="../MemoryMarkers/memoryMarkers.html">Memory Markers</a>
            <!--
            Drop Down Menu:
            DIY
            Purchases
            (Both to have holiday/event selectors on right of page)
            -->
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="../MemoryMarkers/memDIY.html">DIY</a></li>
                <li><a href="../MemoryMarkers/memPurchase.html">Purchases</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parentMenu"><a href="../Reviews/Reviews.html">Reviews</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="../Reviews/Games.html">Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Reviews/Gear.html">Gear</a></li>
                <li><a href="../Reviews/Learning.html">Learning</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parentMenu"><a href="../Blog/mmBlog.html">Blog</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Fit Momma</li>
                <li>Minimal Momma</li>
                <li>Modern Momma</li>
                <li>Organic Momma</li>
                <li>Organizing Queen</li>
                <li>Savings Savvy</li>
                <li>Tech Savvy</li>
                <li>Traditional Momma</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My css code:

```
body {
background-color: beige;
color: lightblue;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
}

header {
background-color: lightblue;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 0;
}
header h1 {
color: cadetblue;
font-family: Arial;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 15px;
display: inline;
}

.navMenu{
display: inline;
margin: 0;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: lightgray;
padding: 5px 10px;
border: thin solid darkgray;
border-radius: 3px;
color: honeydew;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu a{
color: azure;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu .sub-menu{
    display: none;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu:hover .sub-menu{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    }

.parentMenu:hover .sub-menu li{
border: thin solid darkgray;
padding: 4%;
background-color: lightgray;
color: honeydew;
text-align: left;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
}

.parentMenu .sub-menu li:hover {
background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.section {
background-color: wheat;
color: darkslategray;
padding: 5px;
float: left;
display: inline;
width: 63%;
margin: 0 1% 1% 1%;
border-radius: 10px;
border: thin solid khaki;
box-shadow: lightgray;
}

#about {
float: right;
width: 30%;
margin: 1% 1% 0 0;
text-align: center;
}

#home{
margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
}

h4, h3 {
color: lightseagreen;
}
```

Comment: make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ethacker/j7tgq95j/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will align the submenu to the left:

```
.navMenu .parentMenu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  left:-1px;
  top:27px;
}

.navMenu .parentMenu:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/am13qur4/

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify where you want to align your drop down elements. Do you want to align all to the right, center or left. I assumed left so try adding the code below. You may need to adjust the left attribute's value and your hover background styling too.

.sub-menu a{

```
position: absolute;
left: 3%;
```

}

Let me know if this helps. Stay warm!

Comment: It didn't work for me, it made my drop down links bunch up. Thanks though!!